# Tag Synonym: [laptop] -> [technical-issues]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

[laptop](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laptop) seems to be pretty useless, but has some valid questions. Grouping them under [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues) would be a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through the questions which had [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues) added to them due to the [merge](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4964/8350) badp made, and have removed it where required. There were a few I wasn't sure what to do with, so I've posted them below. Feel free to re-tag them if you have any ideas on appropriate tags.

[How can I connect my Xbox 360 to Xbox Live through my Laptop?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8028/how-can-i-connect-my-xbox-360-to-xbox-live-through-my-laptop)

Comment: Voted to close the first, and changed the tag to "performance", since it's slightly closer to being accurate. I untagged the last, I figured it wasn't worth agonizing over the exact tagging of a closed question :P

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how [laptop](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laptop) is a synonym of [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues), even if some users use it that way. The tag should probably just be deleted, with the [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues) being in it's place where required.

Answer (score -3):

Merge made, synonym not created.

Comment: -1 Many of the questions tagged with laptop were not describing technical issues, so a merge was not appropriate.